# PHP Asana API createInWorkspace failing on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, asana, scientific-notation, asana-api

I'm writing an integration to post tasks into Asana, using the official [Asana PHP Client](https://github.com/Asana/php-asana).

Locally - using Google App Engine Launcher - my script is running as intended and the Asana task is created.

Remotely, I'm getting an error from the createInTask API call. I've tracked this down to the response returned within `\Asana\Client::request`, which contains an error object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => projects: [0]: Unknown object: 142133526971480
    [help] => For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors
)
```

Interestingly, the project I'm inserting the task into has ID `142133526971484` - note that this is identical to the ID given in the error above, except the least significant digit.

Now on inspecting the request sent to Asana, I can see the data sent in `$response->request->payload`. Locally - where the code works, this gives:

```
{"data":{"name":"Test title","projects":[142133526971484]}}
```

But running the same script on GAE gives:

```
{"data":{"name":"Test title","projects":[1.4213352697148e+14]}}
```

In the live data, the project ID is in scientific notation and has dropped the last digit.

I'd always thought scientific notation was more of an output format than how the data is actually stored, but it seems likely that this is the cause of the incorrect project ID.

I've tried casting the data as a string before making the call but obviously it's being sent as a POST request, so is not type-specific.

Has anyone seen this or a similar issue before? I wonder if it's a difference in configuration between the GAE-flavoured PHP on live and that on local - something like a `data_precision` setting?

Comment: Hi have you been able to resolve your issue? If not, can you narrow this down further to what you are passing down to the Asana client library? I'd like to see if I can help sort an Asana issue, but it looks likely to me that the issue is upstream.

Comment: As a heads up, this seems like an issue resolved here: https://github.com/Asana/php-asana/pull/32
We'll be looking to publish the client library with this fix in soon.